# What's a workaround for Chrome for Android's incorrect clientX and clientY behavior?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, touch, dom-events

In Chrome for Android versions 16 and 18 (at least) there is a bug that reports `clientX` and `clientY` incorrectly. If the page is scrolled the values of `clientX/Y` will be incorrect for at least the `touchstart` event, though not the `click` event. There is a bug for it here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117754

Which contains this example, that you can try yourself: http://www.apprisant.com/tab/cd.html

I have made a similar example with canvas here: http://codepen.io/simonsarris/full/dJcvn

These examples work on other mobile browsers (including the plain old Android Browser) but Chrome for Android seems to have broken clientX/Y on (at least some) touch events when scrolled.

Interestingly, clientX and clientY are not broken on the `click` event like they are on `touchstart`.

**My question is, what's the best workaround to get clientX and clientY working consistently across browsers?** It appears that offsetting with `window.scrollX` and `window.scrollY` will "solve" the issue, but a good workaround needs to:

1. Determine that the browser is afflicted or not, preferably without making the user do anything and without resorting to checking the userAgent (so not making any assumptions of specific browser versions). In other words, **how do we tell which browsers have bad values for `clientX` and `clientY`?**
2. Solve the issue reliably and only on those browsers where it needs solving (presumably, only Chrome for Android and only specific versions of it, as future versions may be fine), Seemingly, offsetting by `window.scrollX/Y` is the only thing that needs to be done here.

Comment: I'm not sure, but i found this discussion of the problem, maybe it will help you: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=141840#c19

Comment: Do you have any reasons beyond using the correct value for telling which browsers have this behavior? The workaround makes conditional checking less efficient than just using a different method for calculating clientX/Y.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply use `e.pageY - window.scrollY` in place of `e.clientY` (or `X`, accordingly).

`e.pageY` will give you where the event happened, and offsetting by `window.scrollY` will "remove the blank space" that is off-screen due to scroll. You COULD conditional check that `e.pageY - window.scrollY === e.clientY`, but since the workaround gives you the correct value, and you have to calculate it to check it anyways, that would be counter-intuitive.

Comment: Hold on something is wrong. Will modify answer shortly, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Using `e.pageY - window.scrollY` in place of `e.clientY` seems very possible assuming that it always equals the proper value. Can we be certain of that?

Comment: If you're looking to get the position on the current viewport that the event happened, yes. `window.scrollY` is the distance the screen is from the top of the document, and `e.pageY` is the distance the event is from the top of the document. There is ONE condition where you'd have to be careful, and that's if you were using some fo-scolling wrapping element instead of the window to scroll the page. Don't know why you would, but there it is.

Comment: I'm not sure that's enough. I need coordinate code for canvas clicks and touches that is bulletproof in as many DOM situations as possible

Comment: @SimonSarris Actually, no I tested, it works even inside of scroll-able elements.

Comment: @SimonSarris As far as I can fathom, this works in every geometric situation possible.

Comment: @SimonSarris The more I think about it, the element your event happens on is irrelevant. `e.pageY` and `window.scrollY` are both event properties related to static page references. The element the event happens to be on makes no difference to their values or functionality.

Comment: @SimonSarris Please let me know if this is working for you! I am actually going to implement something soon that will use this, I'd like to know if I'm WAY off before I get started. Thanks!

Comment: I'm accepting this, but haven't completed testing yet. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @SimonSarris of course! Let me know what your testing yields =)

Comment: Good news from the other front, Google has patched and closed the two related bugs. We can expect them to land in Chrome mobile "soon" https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117754 https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=141840

Answer (score 3):

I would start by checking that

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

is used. This has fixed a LOT of positional problems in mobile browser applications, particularly with Android. Not sure if it would help your particular problem, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe for `touchstart` event on the canvas and use the `.offset()` and `e.pageX` to get the position within the canvas.

```
$('#my-canvas').on('touchstart', function (startEvent) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();

    $(this).on('touchmove', function (moveEvent) {
        var pos = {
            x: moveEvent.pageX - offset.left,
            y: moveEvent.pageY - offset.top
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Will this work for all possible DOM configurations? I used to use PageX/Y and offset but had to stop because the way Firefox treated the offset was different than other browsers. I seem to remember inline divs being the issue but I don't recall now.

Comment: `canvas` is inline by default and it works. You'll have to try and see. Also, you can also special-case Chrome to use this and rely on `clientX` for other browsers.

Comment: this actually works on all browsers and OS except chrome over android.
once you pinch and zoom the page, the offset becomes scaled(greather than what it should. I don't know how to solve it.